# SLF4J getLogger performance impact using Log4j2

Tags: slf4j, log4j2

What will be performance impact if we use following in logging statements in a centralized logging class.

```
class LogUtil {
    public static debug(String message) {
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getClassName  ()).debug(message);
    }
}
```

I am using SLF4J with log4j2.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you don't follow the example provided in log4j. If you really want a centralized way to do logging, then you should try aspect oriented programming like aspect4j.

what I can see here are two places where you'd have performance impact:

1. you are getting stack trace of the current thread, which could be time consuming compared to a simple Class.getName()
2. you are getting an element from the stack trace, and then its class name

Answer (score 0):

SLF4J `LoggerFactory.getLogger(..)` was intended to be called a small number of times, compared to, say, `Logger.debug(..)`. Method `getLogger(..)` can do lot of bookkeeping before it returns a `Logger` instance, so its better to avoid this pattern (or at least read the Java sources).

SLF4J already does your "centralized logging". But if want, you could create your own facade, like:

```
public class MyLoggerFactory {
    public static MyLogger getLogger() {
        final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(
                  Thread.currentThread()
                        .getStackTrace()[2]
                        .getClassName());
        return new MyLogger(logger);
    }
}

public class MyLogger {
    private final Logger logger;

    class MyLogger(Logger logger) { this.logger = logger; }

    public void debug(Object message) {
        logger.debug(message);
    }
}

class SomeClass {
    private static final MyLogger logger = MyLoggerFactory.getLogger();

    public void method() {
         logger.debug("Log something");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One other downside to this approach is that Log4j's location information will point to the debug method in the LogUtil class, which seems to be what you are duplicating. Log4j's method for obtaining location information is normally much faster than what would be done here.